# How to custom rewrite rule in expression engine?

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to make a custom url like this
http://example.com/entertainment/celebrity/call_me_caitlyn_breaks_the_internet

And i wrote the rewrite rule as follows

RewriteRule ^entertainment/celebrity/(.*?)$ index.php?/news_article/$1 [L]

As well as

RewriteRule ^entertainment/celebrity/(.*?)$ index.php?/news_article/celebrity/$1 [L]

Does not work both of them. How to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go, bruva:

```
RewriteRule ^entertainment/celebrity/(.+)$ news_article/celebrity/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That should do the trick. Please report back if it works.

**Edit**

Add QSA to the rule flags if you have query strings!

Comment: Still not work.

Comment: Works on one of my development servers (I'll double check in about an hour). It needs to be **after** your index.php rewrite rules. Can you edit your question and post your entire htaccess file?